# How to know the URL of my OdataService in SAP HANA?

Tags: odata, hana-xs, hana-studio

I created an oData service within Hana Studio.

I'd like to access it from a sapui5 application, but I don't even know what the url is supposed to be so I can't test it.

Does anyone know how to build this url? I know you need hostname and port number, but what about everything else?

My package name is:

> global-system.schema.XS_V1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone having the same issue:

Appereantly when you click 'run as xs service' in Hana Studio, it could try to open it from the file location, and will give the following error:

> Cannot find file 'C:\Windows\system32\YOURLINK'

Simply copy the link and paste it in the browser, should then work fine.

To prevent this from happening, go to window -> preferences -> general -> web browser -> select 'use external browser'.

It should work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

The URL to your XS OData service is always constructed as follows:

```
https://your.hostname.here/com/example/package/path/yourservice.xsodata
```

The host might include the port of your XS engine if it is not the standard port. The package path (`com/example/package/path/`) equals your OData service namespace so in your case it would be `gloabl-system/schema/XS_V1/`.